# linux shared memory mutex, struct with pointer to shared mutex

Tags: linux, mutex

Im working on porting some existing windows code over to linux, and I've come across something I'm not entirely sure how to handle.

The code is originally RTX windows, and must be deterministic. The first thing I've come across is a structure that contains a semaphore and mutex objects, and sets up pointers to the mutex and semaphore to be passed around/used by other callers.

```
volatile struct mystruct{
 volatile pthread_mutex_t   *qmutexid
 volatile sem_t             *qsemid
 volatile int               processID
 volatile int               msize
 volatile char              msgarray[]
}
```

this struct is cast over a large piece of memory that has data coming in and out of it via a linked list queue, but the semaphore and mutexes are a necessity to enure integrity.

What i want to know is if they following assignment for the pointer is valid.

```
myfunctioninit (*qname, msg_size, depth)
{
struct muStruct    struct1
 pthread_mutex_t   mutexQueAccess

 status = pthread_mutex_init(&mutexQueAccess, null)

struct1->qmutexid = mutexAccess

}
```

The other part of this, is that mutex's in windows are assigned/accessed by name. Other processes need access to this mutex, how do i go about doing it so the mutex can be shared across multiple processes/thread?

Comment: Note: there is a semicolon missing after the struct definition.

Comment: most (all?) `volatile` are unneeded; you will use some synchronization to access these data and this synchronization implies an optimization barrier.